# Three.js lookAt function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, three.js

So, I try to use lookAt function, as I want zombies to go towards the character. The problem seems to be that it doesn't even turn correctly, but on weird angles. This is what I did:

> var pos = new THREE.Vector3(self.position.x - player.x,
>   self.position.y, self.position.z - player.z) self.lookAt(pos)

so yeah, what's the problem? I have a theory that I need to somehow get the relative position of a player, but I don't know how to do that.

Just tried

> lookAt(Player)

Still doesn't work:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLkP3.png)

Comment: From [the `lookAt` documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt) : "Rotates the object to face a point in world space.". Just give it the coordinated of the player

Answer (score 2):

If neither the zombies nor the player are parented to anything than you should be able to use

```
zombieMesh.lookAt(playerMesh.position);
```

Note that `lookAt` makes the positive Z axis of the model point at the target.

```js
'use strict';  // eslint-disable-line

/* global THREE, document, requestAnimationFrame  */

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas});

  const fov = 60;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const zNear = 0.1;
  const zFar = 1000;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
  camera.position.set(14, 8, 6);
  camera.lookAt(-2, -2, 0);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    light.position.set(0, 20, 0);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  {
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    light.position.set(1, 2, 4);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  const groundGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(50, 50);
  const groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xCC8866});
  const groundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeometry, groundMaterial);
  groundMesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * -.5;
  groundMesh.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(groundMesh);
  
  const zombieGeo = new THREE.ConeBufferGeometry(1, 1, 6);
  zombieGeo.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(Math.PI * 0.5));
  const zombieMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 'green', flatShading: true});
  const zombieMeshes = [];
  function makeZombie(x, z) {
    const zombieMesh = new THREE.Mesh(zombieGeo, zombieMat);
    scene.add(zombieMesh);
    zombieMesh.position.set(x, 1, z);
    zombieMeshes.push(zombieMesh);
  }
    
  for (let v = -5; v <= 5; v += 5) {
    makeZombie(v, -10);
    makeZombie(v,  10);
    makeZombie(-5, v);
    makeZombie( 5, v);
  }
  
  const playerGeo = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 6, 4);
  const playerMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 'red', flatShading: true});
  const playerMesh = new THREE.Mesh(playerGeo, playerMat);
  scene.add(playerMesh);
    
  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    
    playerMesh.position.set(Math.sin(time) * 6, 1, Math.cos(time) * 6);

    for (const zombieMesh of zombieMeshes) {
      zombieMesh.lookAt(playerMesh.position);
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/99/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its a first person game, so I think there's a tricky work around you can use...

```
    function ZombieDirectionChanger(o){
                console.log("Camera position has changed");
                zombie.lookAt(camera.position);
                console.log("Zombie has been rotated towards you");
            }

    controls.addEventListener('change', ZombieDirectionChanger);
```

Essentially, because you'll always have your "eyes" through the camera, you can have the zombies follow you wherever your "eyes" are. The function says to change the zombie position, and the event listener is listening to camera change.

I don't see any sample code, but make sure you're lookAt statements are in scope of the object! I'm guilty of that happening to me...

Answer (score -1):

When you use `lookAt` in ThreeJS, it is smart enough to automaticly make the calculations from the positions of the objects, but your code i failing, since you try to calculate the direction around the object, where it should look

Just make your code shorter:

```
self.lookAt(player);
```

Comment: The doc says only `lookAt` accepts either 3 coordinates, or a Vector3. Can it extract the coordinates from an object ?

Comment: @Seblor When you pass 1 argument to `lookAt`, it calls `Vector3d.copy` to copy information out of it to a temporary object, this only looks if the object has the keys `x`, `y`, `z`, and you can see in the question that the `player` object has these 3 properties, so it is valid (it could even be the case that the `player` object from the question already is a `Vector3d`, but from what the op has exposed from this, it should already work)

Comment: I did not know it would do a copy, and that Vector3.copy worked like that. Thanks !

Comment: @Seblor I also learned that when I was browsing the source: [Object3D.lookat](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js#L322) [Vector3d.copy](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Vector3.js#L104)

Comment: Did just what you said. It doesn't work, the zombie just point in completely different direction

Comment: @EmmanuelDolderer That might be because the the model has the front on a differend place then where threejs expects it to be. Try `self.rotation.y += Math.PI / 2` after the lookat to rotate it 90 degrees